# SpringBoot/PostgreSQL:PLSQLException: syntax at or near ":"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am building a springboot application, with postgreSQL as my DB. I need to fetch data from backend by a custom query, which I have mentioned in my repository file as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Roles, Long>{
  @Query(value="select * from roles where role_date::timestamp::date = CURRENT_DATE", nativeQuery=true)
  List<Roles> findByroleDate();
}
```

The query is working fine if I execute it directly on PGAdmin, but through code it is throwing an error stating `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"`

What could possibly be the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What data type is `role_date`? Casting that twice seems rather pointless

Comment: timestamp. I found this method to compare just the date from DB off the internet, and it worked upon trying directly on DB, so I went ahead with it :D

Comment: If that is already a `timestamp` then casting it to `timestamp` won't change anything

Comment: Yeah...true. To be honest I didn't pay much attention to it as it worked. My bad. Anyways thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is confused about the `::` operator. You can workaround that by using the `cast()` operator:

```
select * from roles where cast(role_date as date) = CURRENT_DATE
```

Casting the column to `timstamp` first is useless if it's a `timestamp`, so you only need the cast to a date to remove the time.

---

If you care about performance and expect an index on `role_date` to be used, you should not cast the column at all:

```
select * 
from roles 
where role_date >= CURRENT_DATE
  and role_date < CURRENT_DATE + 1
```